# Debug port forwarding for using Jupyter notebook remotely

Tags: ssh, python, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to use Jupyter notebook on a remote computer. The setup is as follows: I have my home laptop, which can ssh to a specific computer on my university's network (e.g., `gateway.myuniv.edu`). Once I am logged to `gateway.myuniv.edu`, I can ssh to the computer on which I would like to run the Jupyter notebook server (e.g. `cluster.myuniv.edu`).

**What works**: I can run the server on the gateway and connect to it from my laptop using local port forwarding, as follows:

On `gateway.myuniv.edu`: `$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888`

On my laptop: `$ ssh -v -N -L 9000:localhost:8888 myusername@gateway.myuniv.edu`

Then on my laptop's browser, I open the url: `http://localhost:9000`

**What doesn't work**: I don't want to run the server on the gateway, since I can't do heavy computations there. I tried to do the following:

On `cluster.myuniv.edu`: `$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888`

On my laptop: `$ ssh -v -N -L 9000:cluster.myuniv.edu:8888 myusername@gateway.myuniv.edu`

Then on my laptop's browser, I open the url: `http://localhost:9000`. This doesn't work: SSH says that the connection is refused.

I don't understand why this would happen and how to debug this, would be happy for any help. Thanks!